# Electric potential and work

Tags: forces, electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy

> A unit positive charge $q$ is placed in an electric field caused due to a positive charge $Q$.  $q$ experiences a force of repulsion $F_R$. We apply an external force ($F_{\rm ext}$) opposite to $F_R$. The test charge moves in the direction opposite to the electric field. Work is done **opposite to** the field. This work done is stored as potential difference.

Now my doubt is  below:

We know that $F_R=-F_\mathrm{ext}$, so two equal and opposite forces are acting on the charge $q$. If they are equal and opposite, they should cancel each other out now, don't they? Then how is work done against the field? Why is the charge $q$ moving in the direction of external force if the repulsive force (equal in magnitude) is opposing it?

Comment: @FreezingFire if the charge is moving at constant speed, then the magnitude of the forces will be equal.

Comment: @garyp That's what happens when i hurry. Of course you are right!

Comment: @FreezingFire I've been there many times myself.   :)

Comment: @FreezingFire. Charge can considered to be in quasi-equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why textbooks bring external forces into their treatment of electric potential. If a test charge $q$ goes from A to B in an electric field, the work done on it by the field is
$$W_{A\to B}=\int_{\mathbf{r}_A} ^ {\mathbf{r}_B} q \mathbf E.d \mathbf r$$
This is the loss in potential energy of $q$, because it is work that $q$, having gone from A to B, can no longer have done on it by the field. So
$$qV_B-qV_A=-\int_{\mathbf{r}_A} ^ {\mathbf{r}_B} q \mathbf E.d \mathbf r$$
[This is perfectly valid even if there are *no* other forces on $q$; in this case $q$ (or the particle carrying it) acquires kinetic energy equal to the electrical potential energy lost.]

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy is associated with a *system*, not a particle.  One must calculate potential energy for *pairs* of *interacting* particles, not individual particles.

$F_{ext}$ is a force external to the system.  It can do external work and raise the energy of the system.  $F_R$ is work internal to the system (and a conservative one), and does not increase the energy of the system.

But there is a connection which can make the ideas  confusing.  The definition of potential energy is $\Delta PE = -W_\mathrm{int}$ when the work is performed by conservative forces.    But sometimes, as in your example, as a consequence of Newton's Third Law the internal work can be calculated by examining the external forces.